# How to push items to beginning of a slide in Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize, tikz-arrows, tikzmark

I have a slide that has some items and then underneath I have a figure, which is define as `tikzpicture`, while I want to point some arrows from items to the figure. The problem is that now both the figure and the items start from the center of the slide, and basically the figure is on top of the items. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 \tikzmark{a}
\item Item 2 \tikzmark{b}
\item Item 3 \tikzmark{c}
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{my-picture}};
    \foreach \i/\j in {(0.5,0.66)/a} \draw [cyan,->] ({pic cs:\j}) -- \i;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting layout should look like this sketch:

[image]

Comment: did you try the `columns` or `tabular` environment?

Comment: You may insert `at (...,...)` after `\node` indicating some appropiate coordinates in order to shift the picture.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch how your slide should look like?

Comment: Are you looking for `\begin{frame}[t]{Test}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 \tikzmark{a}
\item Item 2 \tikzmark{b}
\item Item 3 \tikzmark{c}
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, yshift=-2cm]
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \foreach \i/\j in {(0.5,0.66)/a} \draw [cyan,->] ({pic cs:\j}) -- \i;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using tabular environment will solve this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test - column}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1 \tikzmark{a}
                \item Item 2 \tikzmark{b}
                \item Item 3 \tikzmark{c}
                \item Item 4
            \end{itemize}

        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
            \foreach \i/\j in {(0.5,0.66)/a} \draw [cyan,->] ({pic cs:\j}) -- \i;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test - tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \parbox{.4\textwidth}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1 \tikzmark{a}
                \item Item 2 \tikzmark{b}
                \item Item 3 \tikzmark{c}
                \item Item 4
            \end{itemize}

        }
        \parbox{.6\textwidth}{
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
            \foreach \i/\j in {(0.5,0.66)/a} \draw [cyan,->] ({pic cs:\j}) -- \i;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This won't work for me, cause items are long sentences, I need the image to be below the items.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using `[t]` and `at(...,...)`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 \tikzmark{a}
\item Item 2 \tikzmark{b}
\item Item 3 \tikzmark{c}
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at(1.5,-2) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{my-picture}};
    \foreach \i/\j in {(0.5,0.66)/a} \draw [cyan,->] ({pic cs:\j}) -- \i;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```